# Angularjs ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Im trying to update some data when the map button is clicked, but the ng-click function doesnt seem to work. Below is my code.

```
<textarea id="xmltest" class="form-control"  style="margin-top:2%; width: 60%;" rows="10" >
Resulting definition:<![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ColumnMapping>
    {{result}}
    <mapping targetIndex='0' sourceIndex='0' dataType='String' businessKey='1' alias='Practice'/>
    <mapping targetIndex='1' sourceIndex='1' dataType='String' businessKey='0' alias='Client_Name'/>
</ColumnMapping>
]]> 
</textarea>

<a style="margin-top: 10%;margin-right: -70%" href="#" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="mapFields()"  id="MappingFields">Map</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    mapFields = function($scope){
    $scope.result= "Code works";
    };
</script>
</body>
```

When I click on the map button, nothing happens. No error is also getting displayed. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is `ng-click="mapFields()"` function?

Comment: you code is more obscure and confusing

Comment: how come your passing $scope as argument? to a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your view  `ng-click="mapFields()"`  it does not pass any argument,

**HTML:**

```
 <body ng-controller="dobController">
     <button ng-click="mapFields()">show result </button>
     {{result}}
  </body>
```

so,your function should be

```
var app = angular.module('todoApp', [])
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.mapFields = function() {
      $scope.result = "Code works";
    };

  }
]);
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OfEKbngPsg1VhKp6KA5o?p=preview)

Comment: I am not downvoted. Without controller how is accesible?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, i tried the above.But getting an error Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Comment: @vr3w3c9 check the demo